# iTextSharp icc/icm color profile - how does it work?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, pdfa

I need to add images to PDF file with specific color profile.

I use iText example [createPdfA](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=226). In all the examples I found, they use the following code:

```
ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile
            .getInstance(new FileInputStream(file));
    writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
```

But the documentation for [setOutputIntents](http://api.itextpdf.com/pdfa/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAWriter.html#setOutputIntents(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ICC_Profile)) is very poor.

I would like to know the following:

1. Does the profile used in setOutputIntents is the profile that will
   be used for all the images in the doc?
2. What is the meaning of the parameters outputConditionIdentifier, outputCondition, registryName and info?
3. In that context, does `writer.setOutputIntents("MyProfile", "", "http://www.mywebsite.com", "", icc);` would give me the same result?
4. How can I test it without actually print the document (print to some file maybe)?